# how to find the rectangular co-ordinates of the dominant/localized objects inside an image.?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, bounding-box

I have an image having several objects in it. for example:- dog, cat, kite, ocean, sky, tree, man

Is there any open-source api which can result the co-ordinates(x1,y1 & x2,y2) of all the object's location present in the image.?

I used the following code

```
import cv2 
image = cv2.imread("image.jpg")
gray=cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
edged = cv2.Canny(image, 10, 250)
(cnts, _) = cv2.findContours(edged.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
idx = 0
for c in cnts:
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
    if w>50 and h>50:
        idx+=1
        new_img=image[y:y+h,x:x+w]
        cv2.imwrite(str(idx) + '.png', new_img)
cv2.imshow("im",image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

So I am using findCountours() & boundingRect() to fetch the co-ordinates, but this code is not running only.

Comment: What did you try so far? Can you upload an example image? IMO, this question is too broad as it is now.

Comment: in order to get the location you need to detect it. How do you go about doing that?

Comment: I've added a sample code in the answer. although the added code is not working.. have a look. also I've uploaded a sample image containing several objects.

Comment: @Manoranjan Instead of adding it as an answer, you should edit your question.

Comment: I did that. thanks Rick..